# Migrating From ColdFusion 7 to ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, migration

I'm planning a migration on a server from ColdFusion MX7 (Server 2003) to ColdFusion 11(Server 2012). There is a Other Server Where I need to migrate from ColdFusion 8 (Server 2008) to ColdFusion 11. Does my System effect in any way when upgrading like tags, or compatibility issues. Does anyone know which steps I should without effecting. I know about the code analyzer that we had in Cf administrator. I want to know if there is anything effected seriously when migrating.

Thanks in Advance
Kiran Kumar

Comment: You can use the Express version or just install CF alongside and hit Tomcat directly on the HTTP port (8085 or whatever).  This will give you a chance to test.  When you satisfied everything works, just repoint your web connectors.

Comment: Sure thank you I Would do that

Answer (score 6):

The **Code Analyzer** helps in migrating your applications to ColdFusion 11 from earlier versions of ColdFusion. However, it checks the same for only two versions back. The Code Analyzer reviews the CFML pages that you specify and informs you of any potential compatibility issues. It detects unsupported and deprecated CFML features, and outlines the required implementation changes that ensure a smooth migration.

As far as the code compatibility is concerned, everything **"should"** work. However, it is recommended to check the code compatibility and deprecated tags (if any). You can refer to https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Deprecated+Features & https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Deprecated+tags,+attributes,+and+values.

I have briefly covered the entire Migration process [here](https://coldfusionsolution.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/migration-of-coldfusion-website-an-overview/). So, will not iterate the same. Also, you can have a look at another helpful article for [Migration Tweaks](https://coldfusionsolution.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/migration-wizard-in-coldfusion/).

Having said that all, it's strongly recommended to test your website on the Testing/Development environment, before moving it on Production.

Hope this gives a better picture of the migration process.

Answer (score 5):

I did the migration in the past, did not face important issue, as everyone have a different system the best solution would 
 - Backup
 - Test the upgrade and see

if it's a production machine, you can copy your machine to a vm and test the upgrade there. it's may be a lot of work, but you can not know if you don't test

Comment: its a test and QA environements

Answer (score 0):

I am currently moving a ColdFusion 9 site to Coldfusion 11 and the way I tested it was to create a separate set of folders on the ms2013 server. I ran them side by side with a duplicate database with a different name for the test site.

I have moved sites up from 5 to 9 with few issues and the only one that really got me in ColdFusion 11 is dbtype in database functions. It has not only been depreciated but will always throw an error if found.

It also depends on how Coldfusion 11 will react to cfcs and other special tags if you use them. I don't so it was a snap.

Examples:

```
  mydatabase
  mydatabase1

  mypagesfolder
  mypagesfolder1

  index.cfm
  index1.cfm
```

Going live was a snap. I just renamed the folders, links*, dsn and renamed index1.cfm to index.cfm.

*Links only need to be changed if posting outside of folder and if so just the path.