# Cannot see migration wizard during Import Settings step of ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfadmin

I am migrating from CF8 to CF11 and at the end I cannot see the automatic migration wizard when Admin console is opened. I want to import all CF8 settings to the new CF11. 
On the other hand, I can see the migration wizard when I am migrating from CF9 to CF11. So does that mean I cannot import ColdFusion 8 settings to the new CF version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating From ColdFusion 7 to ColdFusion 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585366/migrating-from-coldfusion-7-to-coldfusion-11). In this answer Anit (formerly with Adobe) mentions that the migration tool only "_checks the same for only two versions back._"

Comment: I'd again note that CF11 is just a few weeks away from no longer getting security updates. And I still stress my comments on your other posts: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458118/what-are-the-advantages-of-allowing-new-coldfusion-servercf11-to-co-exist-with). I'd recommend not stopping at CF11, especially if you already have CF2016. That said, you may be able to set up a Developer copy of CF10, run the Migration Wizard, fix issues, upgrade to CF2016, run the Migration Wizard again, then fix those issues. I still say there are a _LOT_ of language improvements in those versions.

Comment: And Tomcat and Verity will probably be your biggest issues.

Comment: And honestly, I'd probably not worry about specific settings from CF8, beyond a reference. Use clean CF2016 settings then modify them as needed.